# Java SimpleDateFormat returns incorrect date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Im working with some dates in Java. Trying to parse some string date inputs to Date objects.
This is done using  SimpleDateFormat.parse(String date).

When I use the SimpleDateFormat of "yyyyMMdd" I would expect it to only parse String dates given in this format, and give errors for all other formats. For eg, it should parse 20000611 as June 06, 2000. But should not be able to parse (and hence throw a ParseException) when given a string in the format of 2000-06-11.

However, this is not the case, it parses this date and does so incorrectly.
Wondering if there is anything I can do to fix this, or if its a mistake on my end. I would expect it to not parse the dates with the dashes. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
dateFormat.parse("20000611");   
dateFormat.parse("2000-06-11");
```

Output are as follows:

```
Thu June 11 00:00:00 NDT 2000 (correct)
Sun Dec 05 00:00:00 NST 1999 (incorrect)
```

Outputs have been updated. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Please edit your question to include a runnable example which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Oh, and by the way `Thu May 11 00:00:00 NDT 2000` is correct, it should be `June`, not `May`

Comment: That's the problem of ```SimpleDateFormat```. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19503019/21017714

Comment: As per javadocs *Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date. The method may not use the entire text of the given string.*

Comment: Use java.time instead. `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` were used up to Java 7 but were too troublesome and therefore were supplanted in Java 8 nearly 10 years ago. Do not touch the old classes in 2023. You have seen a little bit of the trouble with them, only a little bit. [Java data time tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: For the record my observed results are just a little bit different, `Sun Jun 11 00:00:00 NDT 2000` and `Mon Dec 06 00:00:00 NST 1999`. I agree that we had wanted an exception instead of the latter.

Comment: Under the linked original questions I recommend [the answer by Basil Bourque here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39338482/5772882) and (immodestly) [mine here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57229701/5772882).

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of problems in your code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
dateFormat.parse(20000611);   
dateFormat.parse(2000-06-11;)
```

1. `SimpleDateFormat` expect a String in `parse`, and none of yours was string.
2. semicolon indicate end of statement, while you put it wrong in last line
3. Even you are passing Strings, the value for first parse won't give you May 11. It should be June

Assuming you are passing in a String for last line (`"2000-06-11"`).  The format does not match with the format you used to create the `dateFormat` and how are you supposed to parse it?  Although I could make up some explanation telling you why that result was produced, that's simply not the way to use `SimpleDateFormat`.

What possibly happened was, date format took `2000` as `yyyy`, `-0` as `MM`, and `6-` as `dd`, and ignoring `11`.

Comment: I would assume that the originally posted code by the OP was a "typo" otherwise we'd be having an entirely different question

Comment: You have not mentioned the most fundamental problem: trying to use the notoriously troublesome and long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class. IMHO not a useful answer.

Comment: Agree.  Should have mentioned that Date is now rarely needed and should switch to java.time

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( "2000-06-11" )
LocalDate.parse( "20000611" , DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE )
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The [Answer by Shum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75851431/642706) is correct. But both that Answer and the Question are using terribly flawed date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Furthermore, your input represents a date-only value, without time-of-day, without time zone or offset-from-UTC. The legacy classes cannot represent a date-only value.

## *java.time*

Your input stings are in standard ISO 8601 formats of the expanded YYYY-MM-DD and the “basic” version YYYYMMDD.

The expanded version is used by default when parsing/generated text.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2000-06-11" ) ;
```

And the “basic” version is predefined in a `DateTimeFormatter` constant object named [`BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "20000611" , DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;
```

Tip: Stick with the expanded version of ISO 8601 formats. More common in my experience. And more readable by humans.

Comment: I highly recommend this answer. The legacy date-time API is not only difficult to understand and work with but also error-prone. Check [this article](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) to learn about it.